# MySQL Recursive CTE hierarchical path

Tags: mysql

I have `categories` table where `parent_id` is self referencing `foreign key`.

**categories table :**

```
select *  from categories;
```

| category_id | name | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T1 | null |
| 2 | T2 | null |
| 3 | T11 | 1 |
| 4 | T12 | 1 |
| 5 | T111 | 3 |
| 6 | T112 | 3 |
| 7 | T1121 | 6 |
| 8 | T1122 | 6 |
| 9 | T121 | 4 |
| 10 | T122 | 4 |
| 11 | T21 | 2 |
| 12 | T211 | 11 |
| 13 | T212 | 11 |
| 14 | T2111 | 12 |

**Expected Output -**

```
select * , 'some path sql' as path from categories;
```

| category_id | name | parent_id | path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T1 | null | T1 |
| 2 | T2 | null | T2 |
| 3 | T11 | 1 | T1 -> T11 |
| 4 | T12 | 1 | T1 -> T12 |
| 5 | T111 | 3 | T1 -> T11 -> T111 |
| 6 | T112 | 3 | T1 -> T11 -> T112 |
| 7 | T1121 | 6 | T1 -> T11 -> T112 -> T1121 |
| 8 | T1122 | 6 | T1 -> T11 -> T112 -> T1122 |
| 9 | T121 | 4 | T1 -> T12 -> T121 |
| 10 | T122 | 4 | T1 -> T12 -> T122 |
| 11 | T21 | 2 | T2 -> T21 |
| 12 | T211 | 11 | T1 -> T21 -> T211 |
| 13 | T212 | 11 | T1 -> T21 -> T212 |
| 14 | T2111 | 12 | T1 -> T21 -> T211 -> T2111 |

**What i have tried :**

I have tried this query but its return 38 rows. I want actual 14 rows.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte_name AS (
    select category_id, name, parent_id , name AS path from  categories 
    UNION ALL
    select c.category_id,c.name,c.parent_id, concat_ws(' -> ', cte_name.path,  c.name) 
    from categories as c
    INNER JOIN cte_name  ON cte_name.category_id = c.parent_id  
)
SELECT * FROM cte_name;
```

I have no idea how to write exact query that will return actual all 14 rows with its path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: @Kendle this answer is to get childrens using recursive cte for a particular parent . my query is to get all the records in the table with there path. I have no idea how to write such query. I can write recursive cte but unable to find the solution for path.

Comment: use  `concat(parent_path,separator,child_id)` in the CTE to build the path?

Comment: I tried it.. it is returning 38 rows. i am editing my answer with what i have tried.  i want just 14 actuall rows.

Comment: please could you give the table definition and sample data, preferably as a dbfiddle

Comment: @Kendle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jhP7NvCzHKwaqbTPXzNNJK/0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CONCAT(parent_path,separator,child_id)` in the CTE to build the path. You need to specify 'WHERE parent_id IS NULL` in the first part of the CTE before the UNION so that we only include paths starting from the roots.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categories (
>     category_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     parent_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>     created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
>     PRIMARY KEY (category_id),
>     FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES categories(category_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
>
> INSERT INTO categories (`name`,`parent_id`) VALUES ( 'T1', null);
> INSERT INTO categories (`name`,`parent_id`) VALUES ( 'T2', null);
> INSERT INTO categories (`name`,`parent_id`) VALUES ( 'T11', 1);
> INSERT INTO categories (`name`,`parent_id`) VALUES ( 'T12', 1);
> INSERT INTO categories (`name`,`parent_id`) VALUES ( 'T111', 3);
> INSERT INTO categories (`name`,`parent_id`) VALUES ( 'T112', 3);
> INSERT INTO categories (`name`,`parent_id`) VALUES ( 'T1121', 6);
> INSERT INTO categories (`name`,`parent_id`) VALUES ( 'T1122', 6);
> INSERT INTO categories (`name`,`parent_id`) VALUES ( 'T121', 4);
> INSERT INTO categories (`name`,`parent_id`) VALUES ( 'T122', 4);
> INSERT INTO categories (`name`,`parent_id`) VALUES ( 'T21', 2);
> INSERT INTO categories (`name`,`parent_id`) VALUES ( 'T211', 11);
> INSERT INTO categories (`name`,`parent_id`) VALUES ( 'T212', 11);
> INSERT INTO categories (`name`,`parent_id`) VALUES ( 'T2111', 12);
> ```

> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE cte_name AS (
>     select category_id, name, parent_id , name AS path from  categories 
>     where parent_id is null
>     UNION ALL
>     select c.category_id,c.name,c.parent_id, concat_ws(' -> ', cte_name.path,  c.name) 
>     from categories as c
>     INNER JOIN cte_name  ON cte_name.category_id = c.parent_id  
> )
> SELECT * FROM cte_name;
> ```
>
> ```
> category_id | name  | parent_id | path                      
> ----------: | :---- | --------: | :-------------------------
>           1 | T1    |      null | T1                        
>           2 | T2    |      null | T2                        
>           3 | T11   |         1 | T1 -> T11                 
>           4 | T12   |         1 | T1 -> T12                 
>          11 | T21   |         2 | T2 -> T21                 
>           5 | T111  |         3 | T1 -> T11 -> T111         
>           6 | T112  |         3 | T1 -> T11 -> T112         
>           9 | T121  |         4 | T1 -> T12 -> T121         
>          10 | T122  |         4 | T1 -> T12 -> T122         
>          12 | T211  |        11 | T2 -> T21 -> T211         
>          13 | T212  |        11 | T2 -> T21 -> T212         
>           7 | T1121 |         6 | T1 -> T11 -> T112 -> T1121
>           8 | T1122 |         6 | T1 -> T11 -> T112 -> T1122
>          14 | T2111 |        12 | T2 -> T21 -> T211 -> T2111
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=29d03f9c106eaa33f65fd4f3ca983ff3)*